# how should name the modifier params in Jetpack compose component which gets two or more modifiers?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, modifier

If we have a compose component which gets two or more modifiers, how should we handle it ?
I mean the naming of modifiers while lint complains changing the name of modifier parameter

Sample code to figure out easily :

```
@Composable
    private fun CompletionSection(iconModifier: Modifier, textModifier: Modifier, isActivated: Boolean, newText: String?) {
        if (isActivated) {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ds_ic_check_circle),
                modifier = iconModifier
                    .wrapContentSize()
                    .padding(top = 18.dp),
                tint = MaterialTheme.colors.positive,
                contentDescription = null
            )
        } else if (!newText.isNullOrBlank()) {
            Surface(
                modifier = textModifier.padding(top = 18.dp),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(32.dp),
                border = BorderStroke(width = 2.dp, color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary.copy(alpha = 0.6f)),
            ) {
                Text(
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                    maxLines = 1,
                    fontSize = 11.sp,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary.copy(alpha = 0.6f),
                    text = newText,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .defaultMinSize(minHeight = 20.dp)
                        .wrapContentSize()
                        .padding(horizontal = 6.dp, vertical = 2.dp),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.android.caption2
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Here, where the function is used →

```
ConstraintLayout(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    constraintSet = decoupledConstraints(
        marginSpacing02 = marginSpacing02,
        marginSpacing01 = marginSpacing01,
        entity = entity
    )
) {
    
    CompletionSection(
        iconModifier = Modifier.layoutId("completedIcon"),
        textModifier = Modifier.layoutId("newTextField"),
        isActivated = isActivated,
        newText = newText
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier

> Composables that accept modifiers to be applied to a specific subcomponent `foo` should name the parameter `fooModifier` and follow the same guidelines above for default values and behavior. Subcomponent modifiers should be grouped together and follow the parent composable's modifier. For example:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ButtonBar(
    onOk: () -> Unit,
    onCancel: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    buttonModifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Row(modifier) {
        Button(onCancel, buttonModifier) {
            Text("Cancel")
        }
        Button(onOk, buttonModifier) {
            Text("Ok")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume the reason for this kind of warning is because you usually have one modifier that has to be applied to the whole view. Having an other modifier in arguments is kind of OK, but, for example if you need to apply `Modifier.align`, you had to duplicate it.

In your case, when you look from where you're using this function, it's hard to tell which modifier will be applied and which is not - it depends on other parameters and you have to know the logic.

I think at least it could have one generic modifier named `modifier`, which would apply for both views, and two named ones - in my opinion this would make the API a bit more predictable. You can chain modifiers like this: `modifier.then(iconModifier).yourModifier()`

Anyway, you can suppress it:

```
@SuppressLint("ModifierParameter")
@Composable
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks, @Philip Dukhov 
Suppressing the lint is not a good practice, in my case I am calling the component form a constraint layout which the modifiers don't have any common items, I update the post to see the usage as well

Comment: @SepidehVatankhah Maintainers may not have thought of your use case, and I think I'm about right in describing their thoughts. And I find nothing wrong with suppressing a warning in such a case when you know what you are doing. For example, you can check [how many times](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/search?q=SuppressLint) it's used in AndroidX, which includes Compose source code. But if you don't like this idea, you can follow my idea with a third `modifier` with the default `Modifier` value.

Comment: Actually, I use this multi modifier in not rare cases, whenever I need to encapsulate a custom view, it needs multiple modifiers 
e.g. if you want to have swipable tab component and make it encapsulate you have to send two modifiers for both tab and horizontalPager here is the link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71057072/while-clicking-on-the-tab-with-horizontalpager-in-android-jetpack-compse-it-jum) 
maybe you have any idea for my other issue as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

Composables are designed to accept only one `Modifier`, so the lint won't be satifsfied no matter how you rename them.
The Composable is something like a unit of interface, and it having multiple modifiers is leaking its inner workings to the outer composables that use it.

Comment: @lyjie So what should we do if we want to encapsulate our component and also give the developer the ability to modify it?

Comment: @SepidehVatankhah it should be modified uniformly (using a single `Modifier`). If there are multiple parts to the composable (like in your case), I guess you have to either have the `if` on the higher composable (as it affects its modifier) or make a separate "switch" composable, that accepts a `boolean` flag and switches between two passed `content` Composables