# While clicking on the tab with HorizontalPager in android Jetpack Compse, it jumps to the last tab

Tags: android, kotlin, tabs, android-viewpager, android-jetpack-compose

While clicking on the **tab** with **HorizontalPager** in android **Jetpack Compse,** it jumps to the last tab
I add the code to see the problem visible

This is my code ->

```
data class TabPage(val title: String?, val icon: ImageVector? = null, var screen: (@Composable () -> Unit)? = null)

@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
fun SwipeableTabLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    tabPages: List<TabPage>
) {
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Surface(color = Color.White) {
        Column {
            TabRow(selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage) {
                tabPages.forEachIndexed { index, tabPage ->
                    Tab(
                        modifier = modifier,
                        selected = index == pagerState.currentPage,
                        onClick = { scope.launch { pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index) } },
                        text = tabPage.title?.let { title -> { Text(text = title) } },
                        icon = tabPage.icon?.let { icon -> { Icon(imageVector = icon, contentDescription = null) } }
                    )
                }
            }


            HorizontalPager(
                state = pagerState,
                count = tabPages.size,
                content = { page -> tabPages[page].screen?.invoke() })
        }
    }
}
```

And this is where it is used ->

```
enum class SnackbarType(val value: String) {
    ERROR("Error"),
    WARNING("Warning"),
    SUCCESS("Success"),
    INFO("Info")
}

@Composable
fun CoreComponentsSnackbarScreen(onNavigate: (Destination) -> Unit) {
    val tabPages = listOf(
        TabPage(title = SnackbarType.ERROR.value, screen = { LoadScreen() }),
        TabPage(title = SnackbarType.WARNING.value, screen = { LoadScreen() }),
        TabPage(title = SnackbarType.SUCCESS.value, screen = { LoadScreen() }),
        TabPage(title = SnackbarType.INFO.value, screen = { LoadScreen() })
    )

    Scaffold(
        content = {
            SwipeableTabLayout(tabPages = tabPages, scrollable = true)
        }
    )
}

@Composable
private fun LoadScreen() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .padding(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
    ) {

        Text(text = "One line")

        Text(text = "Two lines")

        Text(text = "One line with action")


        Text(text = "Two lines with action")
    }
}
```

If the LoadScreen() function just loads a simple text, it works well but when you add more items, while clicking it jumps to the last tab

e.g. with this LoadScreen() works fine ->

```
@Composable
private fun LoadScreen() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .padding(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
    ) {

        Text(text = "One line")

}
```

Comment: Your code is too massive to understand the problem just by looking at it, also it doesn't run at all - the first thing I can't find is `LoadSnackbar`, but also you use a lot of stuff from `R.string.` and custom colors, which I don't have either. The more code in your question, the less anyone will be willing to try to run it, even if all the elements are present. Also, you will often be able to find the problem yourself, as long as you remove irrelevant parts of the code along the way to [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @PhilipDukhov fair enough, updated

Comment: Nicely done! What Compose/Accompanist versions are you using? It seems working fine to me, I'm using **1.1.0** and **0.23.0** accordingly. If you can reproduce the problem on the latest versions same as mine, please describe clearly your steps to reproduce, perfectly with a gif/video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem exists in Kotlin **version 1.5.31** and **compose version 1.0.5** with upgrading to the latest Kotlin version **1.6.10** and relatively upgrading compose version, bug fixed.